# How to connect sql database to android application using wcf?

Tags: android, xml, database, sql-server-2008, wcf

I currently use xmlstring to pass values between android application and sql server. But now i need to make this connection through **wcf**. so how can i do this one.

Comment: Do you already have a working wcf?

Comment: No i am actually started working on this. completely new to this

Comment: So the way you connect to the wcf depends on the way you expose the service. My suggestion is to configure it as restful service and pass the data using Json.

Comment: so  pass data as json will be better, as i am not used to it do you have any tutorials or some kind of examples, so that i can understand easily..!

Answer (score 0):

If your buliding the service, you might want to consider using Web api instead of wcf as it more simple to configure.

[The basics of building an HTTP service using ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)

You can use a library as [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) to get the data from the server.
Ater you fetch the data, in Json format, you can parse it using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: is it a secured layer of connection.